# Magento - Display attribute image in base image whenever an attribute is selected?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is there any extension that displays the attribute image in base image location whenever is selected?

I found some extensions that display image from single product whenever an attribute is selected in configurable product like the link below…

http://amasty.com/image-based-configurable-products.html

But I couldn’t find any extension that displays attribute image in base image…

If there is no extension available, does anyone know how to code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have insert attribute image then you can replace base image url with attribute image url using javascript.

If you have not show image with attribute then you can use this extension

https://github.com/jreinke/magento-attribute-option-image

Comment: Can you please give me a sample of javascript?